# Not able to send data on consecutive clocks in uvm driver

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am trying to write a uvm driver for a protocol such that it sends a single valid with address and data on posedge of clock and then wait for the ready signal from dut. As soon as ready is sampled as high, it drops the valid and starts driving another transaction.
The issue I am facing is that with below code, if the ready is always high, I am not able to drive transactions on every clock, there is a wait of 2 clocks before next transaction is send. How do I send transactions on each clock synchronized with posedge.
Below is my driver code :

```
virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
forever
begin
seq_item_port.get_next_item(trans);
drive(trans);
seq_item_port.item_done;
end
endtask

virtual task drive(packet trans);

 @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);// clk 1 wait 
  vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 'b1;
  vif.mod_p.cb.addr<= trans.addr;
  vif.mod_p.cb.data<= trans.data;
 
  @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);// clk 2 wait 

  while(!vif.mod_p.cb.ready)   
  @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);

  vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 0;

 endtask
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine drive task into the run_phase.

```
virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
   forever
     begin
      @(posedge vif.cb)
      if (vif.cb.valid)
        seq_item_port.item_done; // drove transaction on previous cycle
      if (seq_item_port.try_next_item(trans)) begin
           vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 'b1;
           vif.mod_p.cb.addr<= trans.addr;
           vif.mod_p.cb.data<= trans.data;
           while(!vif.mod_p.cb.ready)  @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);
      end else
          vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 0;
     end
endtask
```

This might not be exactly what you need, but should get you very close. Your driver essically becomes a state machine.

Comment: Sure, this works but I have a question, if I remove "clk 1 wait" in my code, it still will work for back to back transactions but i think the first transaction might not be driven on posedge, but will still be sampled at next posedge by dut? Am i right ? Is it okay to not drive the first transaction on posedge  like not have "clk 1 wait" in my code above?

Comment: Clocking block drive statements are always _driven_ on the next clock edge

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is  that because of skew, the data is driven a little later than  the posedge  because of skew to avoid race condition, so in my code, if I remove "clk 1 wait", the DUT will be able to sample data on every posedge  "clk 2 wait"  like back to back transactions, i dont understand if there is a need to have  "clk 1 wait" in my code

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
    virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    forever
    begin
      @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);// clk 1 wait
      seq_item_port.try_next_item(trans);
      if(trans !=null)
        drive(trans);
      seq_item_port.item_done;
    end
    endtask
    virtual task drive(packet trans);
      vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 'b1;
      vif.mod_p.cb.addr<= trans.addr;
      vif.mod_p.cb.data<= trans.data;
      // @(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);// clk 2 wait 
      while(!vif.mod_p.cb.ready)   
      //@(posedge vif.mod_p.cb);
      vif.mod_p.cb.valid<= 0;
   endtask
```

Can you try using "try_next_item" in your code? it will help in resolving this issue.
Also note that, I moved clock wait in forever loop and I have commented clk2 wait and clk3 wait as it is not necessary.